# UIColor return wrong values for dark mode colors

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios13, ios-darkmode

I have a custom `UITextField` subclass which changes its border color when typing something in it. I'm listening for changes by calling

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and then, in `textFieldDidChange(_:)` I'm doing:

```
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "testColor")?.cgColor
```

Where `testColor` is a color defined in Assets.xcassets with variants for light and dark mode. The issue is that `UIColor(named: "testColor")?.cgColor` seems to always return the color for the light mode.

Is this a bug in iOS 13 beta or I'm doing something wrong? There's [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/ov1d1u/DarkModeTest) with the code which exhibits this behaviour. Run the project, switch to dark mode from XCode then start typing something in the text field.

Comment: did you try to run this on device and do that?

Comment: Yes, it does the same.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

#### Short answer

In this situation, you need to specify which trait collection to use to resolve the dynamic color.

```
self.traitCollection.performAsCurrent {
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "testColor")?.cgColor
}
```

or

```
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "testColor")?.resolvedColor(with: self.traitCollection).cgColor
```

#### Longer answer

When you call the `cgColor` method on a dynamic `UIColor`, it needs to resolve the dynamic color's value. That is done by referring to the current trait collection, `UITraitCollection.current`.

The current trait collection is set by UIKit when it calls your overrides of certain methods, notably:

- UIView

  - draw()
  - layoutSubviews()
  - traitCollectionDidChange()
  - tintColorDidChange()
- UIViewController

  - viewWillLayoutSubviews()
  - viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  - traitCollectionDidChange()
- UIPresentationController

  - containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
  - containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()
  - traitCollectionDidChange()

However, outside of overrides of those methods, the current trait collection is not necessarily set to any particular value. So, if your code is not in an override of one of those methods, and you want to resolve a dynamic color, it's your responsibility to tell us what trait collection to use.

(That's because it's possible to override the `userInterfaceStyle` trait of any view or view controller, so even though the device may be set to light mode, you might have a view that's in dark mode.)

You can do that by directly resolving the dynamic color, using the UIColor method [`resolvedColor(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238042-resolvedcolor). Or use the UITraitCollection method [`performAsCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/3238082-performascurrent), and put your code that resolves the color inside the closure. The short answer above shows both ways.

You could also move your code into one of those methods. In this case, I think you could put it in `layoutSubviews()`. If you do that, it will automatically get called when the light/dark style changes, so you wouldn't need to do anything else.

#### Reference

[WWDC 2019, Implementing Dark Mode in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/)

Starting at 19:00 I talked about how dynamic colors get resolved, and at 23:30 I presented an example of how to set a `CALayer`'s border color to a dynamic color, just like you're doing.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the accepted one as using the suggested code works even when I'm changing to dark mode from the Environment Overrides button in Xcode. Thanks for clarifying how dynamic `UIColor` works, too.

Comment: I have a similar issue to the OP's, when I set a named colour (created in .xassets with colours set to Any and Dark appearances) to some buttons' border it works inconsistently, some buttons appear with the light colour and some with the dark colour. Another problem regarding layer.borderColor and Dark Mode is that when I change from Light to Dark mode (and vice-versa) in iOS settings, it only updates the colour of the buttons' border (even when it displays the correct appearance of the color) if I redraw the buttons (pop the vc and push again). Probably a bug right? (tested in xcode 11 b6)

Comment: Btw, the inconsistent behaviour I described above happens on iOS 12 (which is weird, because some borders appear with the dark appearance even though iOS 12 has no Dark Mode support) and the need the redraw to get the correct colour after changing modes occurs in iOS 13b

Comment: @LeeAndrew did you find a fix?

Comment: @airowe Me neither. This worked for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312095/ios13-dark-mode-change-not-recognized-by-tableview-cell

Comment: @rs7 Nailed it, thanks! That worked for me. Here's a direct link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58312205/1496693

Comment: @Kurt Revis, is there an equivalent answer for macOS? I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: I was having issues with some `UIView` subclasses not respecting dark mode variants of my XCAsset colors but:

`UIColor(named: "testColor")?.resolvedColor(with: self.traitCollection)` fixed it.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not work. UIColor.text always returns black when in dark mode which makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add invisible subview on you view and it will track traitCollectionDidChange events.

example:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    func secondaryStyle() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "borderColor")?.cgColor

        moon.updateStyle = { [weak self] in
            self?.secondaryStyle()
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var moon: Moon {
        (viewWithTag(Moon.tag) as? Moon) ?? .make(on: self)
    }

    final class Moon: UIView {
        static var tag: Int = .max - 1

        var updateStyle: (() -> Void)?

        static func make(on view: UIView) -> Moon {
            let moon = Moon()
            moon.tag = Moon.tag
            view.addSubview(moon)
            return moon
        }

        override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
            super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
            guard previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle != traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle else { return }
            triggerUpdateStyleEvent()
        }

        func triggerUpdateStyleEvent() {
            updateStyle?()
        }
    }
}
```