# UIView's shadowpath color doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-darkmode, shadowpath

I have a `UIView` and I set a `shadowPath` for it like this:

```
func addShadow() {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = self.containerView.frame.height/2
    self.containerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.containerView.frame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    self.containerView.layer.shadowRadius = cornerRadius
    self.containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(named: "whiteColor")?.cgColor
}
```

And this is `whiteColor`:

[image]

And now my problem is

> When I change the appearance of the phone, the `shadowPath`'s color doesn't change automatically. What should I do to make the color dynamic?

Comment: Do all your color stuff in layoutSubview or viewDidLayoutSubviews. Then you set the color to a dynamic variable that will compute it's value based on the traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle

Comment: @andromedainiative Are you sure it's the best way? I have many views that have shadow, Is it right that to set all of them in `layoutSubView`?

Comment: I mean there is no silver bullet generic solution that I know of. We ended up moving all our color setup these methods. You can read more about it here. Unless you use the same view controller in every view you have you will have to do some updating of colors manually. 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface

Comment: @andromedainiative nice document thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All layer properties don't react to color changes automatically (due to the conversion to `CGColor`).

Instead, react to trait collection changes and re-set the properties when the color appearance changes:

```
override open func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if #available(iOS 13, *), self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        // re-set your properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I should override this method in every `ViewController`?! I need a more generic solution!

Comment: Only were you set layer properties. But yes, it's a pain. I created a `BaseView` that provides `UIColor` properties for all those layer properties and handles appearance changes. But now I ended up with 4 different `BaseView`s for buttons, table view cells, etc...

Comment: Please call super.traitCollectionDidChange

Answer (score 2):

So this is what worked for me - it's a mix  between [Frank Schlegel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541016/frank-schlegel)'s answer and between Kurt Revis's [answer to the cgColor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165239/uicolor-return-wrong-values-for-dark-mode-colors)

---

```
override open func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

   if #available(iOS 13, *), self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {

       SubmissionOptionsMenu.layer.shadowColor = 
              UIColor.label.resolvedColor(with: self.traitCollection).cgColor
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add 
`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` 
in your function.It might solve your issue. In alternative way you will add color in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` didn't work, and I think overriding `viewDidLayoutSubViews` is not the best! cause I should override this method in every ViewController! I need a more generic solution!

Comment: The best generic solution I can think of is to create a base view class that handles trait changes and derive from that for all views that need it.

Comment: Can u run it in main thread ? its might be work .   I mean using-  func addShadow() 
 { DispatchQueue.main.async { //your code here}  }

Comment: @NahidRaihan nothing happened!

Comment: 1.from where did you call this function ?  2. Add self.view.layoutIfNeeded() starting line in method and add again in  before ending .

Comment: add it in ```viewWillAppear() ``` please.