# ios13 Dark Mode change not recognized by tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, ios-darkmode

I'm checking my existing app to work correctly with the new introduced dark mode feature of ios 13.

Everything seems to work fine, only the cell background in one of my tableViews is not refreshed according the mode (dark / light).

If the app starts in dark mode, the cells also show the correct dark background. If the mode changes while the app is in background, the cell background color is not changed. The cell label switches the color correct.

for the tableview cells i use the following func for a gradient:

```
func gradient(frame:CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer { 

    let gradColor1 = UIColor(named: "gradientBright")!
    let gradColor2 = UIColor(named: "gradientDark")!

    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = frame
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    layer.colors = [
        gradColor1.cgColor,
        gradColor2.cgColor
    ]
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    return layer
}
```

i add the gradient background to the table cells in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

with the following code

```
cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.bounds), at: 0)
```

Any idea, why only the gradient func does not seem to get the correct colors after a mode change happened while app active or in background?

Regards

Comment: Adding layer in that function cause duplicated layers. Only add layer if it's not already added before.

Comment: I had this issue before, I post an answer with the link to my issue. Check it out and let me know if you had any further questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Cell` will detect, `layer` will not! You must manually update all `layer` adaptations in the `cell` for example.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        removeAndReaddGradientIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

[More description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016866/how-to-detect-light-dark-mode-change-in-ios-13)

Comment: and this has to be done (adding inititally and replacing) in uitableviewcell? Can not make it to have the gradientlayer added with correct size (self.bounds, self.contentView.bound and also self.backgroundView.bounds seem to be smaller than display width)

Comment: Yep. `layoutSubviews` is the function you need to override to recalculate the size whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

If this gradient is on every cell of this type, then it should simply be a part of the cell, not inserted by the containing view controller. Then, in your cell, you can implement:

```swift
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
  super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

  if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle {
    // reload the gradient layer to react
  }
}
```

You could also implement this in your view controller and reload data but it's messier.

Comment: Can you eventually point me how to add the gradient layer in uitableviewcell and make sure it's only added once? Didn't know about this problem as all tutorials and documentation told me to add it in uitableview class.